# Respond to request with external URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to respond to a particular request in different ways based on the referrer. The code is pretty simple:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {        
    if (req.headers.accept.indexOf('image') != -1) {
        res.sendfile('http://example.com/someimage.png');
    } else {
        res.render('views/index');
    }
});
```

Basically, in the first conditional, I'd just like to 'pass long' an image from an external URL. I assume I may have to stream this file through my server, but is there another way to just pass the link directly?

Comment: Please confirm this code uses the express framework. And add the relevant tag.

Comment: Confirmed. Indeed it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming you use express as it seems, you can use [redirect](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) :

```
res.redirect('http://example.com/someimage.png');
```

If you want the browser to consider the new URL as permanent, add the relevant status code :

```
res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com/someimage.png');
```